# VBScript output as Excel worksheet not working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I've got a page that will either display information in an HTML table or output that same info as an excel file.

The HTML view is working fine, but the excel portion fails with : (500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.)

Ideally, if its possible to separate the excel portion of the code I'd rather have that as the final product, but I need to get it working first. I'd appreciate any ideas.

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Session("CurrentPageTitle") = "Test Transaction Summary" %>
<%
Response.Buffer = TRUE
if Request.Form("present") = "xls" then 
set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set objWB = objXL.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\temp\xl.xlsx") 
Set objWS = objXL.ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets("Sheet1") 
numRow = 9

end if

if Request.Form("present") <> "xls" then 
%>
<!--#include file="../common/header.inc"-->
<%
end if 
varState = Request.QueryString("state")
varCustomerIdentifier = Request.Form("Customer")
CustomerArray = Split(varCustomerIdentifier,",")
varCustomer = CustomerArray(0)
varSub = CustomerArray(1)
varCity = CustomerArray(2)

if Request.Form("Summary") = "user" and varState <> "u" then
    'Should not be here, form navigation glitch - go to GetUserParam.asp
    location.href="GetUserParam.asp?f=" & varCustomerIdentifier & "&t=user"
else
if varState = "u" then
    varYesterday = Request.Form("Smonth") + "/" + Request.Form("Sday")+ "/"  + Request.Form("Syear")
    varToday = Request.Form("Emonth") + "/" + Request.Form("Eday")+ "/"  + Request.Form("Eyear")
elseif varState = "m" then
    varYesterday = month(date()) & "/1/" & year(date())
    varToday = date()
    strYesterday = dateadd("d",-1,date())
elseif varState = "y" then
    varYesterday = "1/1/" & year(date())
    varToday = date()
    strYesterday = dateadd("d",-1,date())
elseif varState = "s" then
    varYesterday = Request.Form("Smonth") + "/" + Request.Form("Sday")+ "/"  + Request.Form("Syear")
    varToday = Request.Form("Emonth") + "/" + Request.Form("Eday")+ "/"  + Request.Form("Eyear")
    varInterval = Request.Form("Interval")
else
    varYesterday = cdate(datepart("m",date()-1) & "/" & datepart("d",date()-1) & "/" & datepart("yyyy",date()-1))
    varToday = cdate(datepart("m",date()) & "/" & datepart("d",date()) & "/" & datepart("yyyy",date()))
end if
if varCustomer = "0" then
    strSQL = "select CustomerNo, SubNo, City, CustomerName from Customer order by CustomerName"
else
    strSQL = "select CustomerNo, SubNo, City, CustomerName from Customer where CustomerNo = " & varCustomer & " and SubNo = " & varSub & " and City = " & varCity & " order by CustomerName"
end if

' sjs
dim DBCONN
set DBCONN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DBCONN.CommandTimeout = 60000
DBCONN.ConnectionTimeout = 60000
DBCONN.Open "DSN=***;UID=***;PWD=***;"  
set DBConnection = DBCONN

set DBQuery = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
DBQuery.ActiveConnection = DBConnection
DBQuery.CommandType = 1
DBQuery.CommandText = strSQL
DBQuery.CommandTimeout = 900
Err.Clear
set dbRS = DBQuery.Execute
AllUpdateCount = 0
AllInquiryCount = 0
AllMTCount = 0
AllETCount = 0
AllTotalCount = 0
index = 0
while not dbRS.EOF
    index = index + 1

    if Request.Form("Summary") = "prevd" then
        strType = "Yesterday"
        strNote = "(from " & varYesterday & ")"
        strFormatSQL = "select distinct [Format] 'formatid' from TransactionSummary where CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and TransactionDate = '" & varYesterday & "'"
    elseif Request.Form("Summary") = "user" then
        strType = "User Specified"
        strFormatSQL = "select distinct [Format] 'formatid' from TransactionSummary where CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and TransactionDate >= '" & varYesterday & "' and TransactionDate <= '" & varToday & "'"
        strNote = "(from " & varYesterday & " to " & varToday & ")"
    elseif Request.Form("Summary") = "mtd" then
        strType = "Month To Date"
        strFormatSQL = "select distinct [Format] 'formatid' from TransactionSummary where CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and TransactionDate >= '" & varYesterday & "' and TransactionDate < '" & varToday & "'"
        strNote = "(from " & varYesterday & " through " & varToday & ")"
    elseif Request.Form("Summary") = "ytd" then
        strType = "Year To Date"
        strFormatSQL = "select distinct [Format] 'formatid' from TransactionSummary where CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and TransactionDate >= '" & varYesterday & "' and TransactionDate < '" & varToday & "'"
        strNote = "(from " & varYesterday & " through " & varToday & ")"
    elseif Request.Form("Summary") = "stats" then
        strType = "Usage Statistics"
        strFormatSQL = "select TransactionDate from TransactionDetail where CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and TransactionDate >= '" & varYesterday & "' and TransactionDate <= '" & varToday & " 11:59:59 PM'"
        strNote = "(from " & varYesterday & " to " & varToday & ")"
    else
        strFormatSQL = ""
    end if

    'very top  
if Request.Form("present") = "xls" then 

    if varCustomer = "0" and index = 1 then
    objXL.Cells(5,2) = strType & " Summary For ALL Customers"
    objXL.Cells(6,2) = strNote
    end if

    if varCustomer ="0" then
    else
    objXL.Cells(5,2) = strType & " Summary For Customer: " & Trim(dbRS.Fields("CustomerName").Value) & " - City " & Trim(dbRS.Fields("City").Value) 
    objXL.Cells(6,2) = strNote
    end if

elseif Request.Form("present") <> "xls" then 

    if varCustomer = "0" and index = 1 then
        Response.Write("<h3>" & strType & " Summary for All Customers<br>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<font size=""-1"">" & strNote & "</font></h3>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<table border=""1"" id=""exCity"" runat=""server"">" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<tr>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Customer</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>City</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Inquiry</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Update</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Total</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("</tr>" & chr(13))
    end if

    ' Customer and City for ALL Customers added above each record top
    if varCustomer = "0" then
    ' Response.Write("<h3><i>" & Trim(dbRS.Fields("CustomerName").Value) & " - Po------------rt " & Trim(dbRS.Fields("City").Value) & "</i></h3>" & chr(13))

    'Customer and City for a single Customer added to very top      
    else
        Response.Write("<h3>" & strType & " Summary for Customer: " & Trim(dbRS.Fields("CustomerName").Value) & " - City " & Trim(dbRS.Fields("City").Value) & "<br>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<font size=""-1"">" & strNote & "</font></h3>" & chr(13))

    'start a table with format request name transatctions at the top  
        Response.Write("<table border=""1"" id=""exCity"" runat=""server"">" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<tr>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Customer</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>City</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Inquiry</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Update</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center""><strong>Total</strong></td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("</tr>" & chr(13))
    end if
end if

    'query db for one Customer
    DBQuery.CommandText = strFormatSQL
    Err.Clear
    set dbRS3 = DBQuery.Execute
    UpdateTotalCount = 0
    InquiryTotalCount = 0
    MTTotalCount = 0
    ETTotalCount = 0
    CustomerTotalCount = 0
    IntervalCounter = 0
    IntervalStart = varYesterday & " 12:00:00 AM"
    while not dbRS3.EOF
        if varState = "s" then
            Difference = datediff("n", IntervalStart, dbRS3.Fields("TransactionDate").Value)
            if (CInt(Difference) < CInt(varInterval)) then
                IntervalCounter = IntervalCounter + 1
            else
                IntervalNext = dateadd("n", varInterval, IntervalStart)
                Response.Write("<tr><td align=""left"">" & IntervalStart & " to&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>" & IntervalNext & "</td><td align=""center"" valign=""middle"">" & IntervalCounter & "</td></tr>" & chr(13))
                IntervalCounter = 0
                IntervalStart = IntervalNext
            end if
        else
            if Request.Form("Summary") = "prevd" then
                strSQL = "select Sum(s.TransactionCount) 'hits', r.RequestName from TransactionSummary as s LEFT JOIN RepositoryDB.dbo.BLS_REQ as r ON s.[Format] = r.RequestID where s.CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and s.SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and s.City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and s.TransactionDate = '" & varYesterday & "' and s.[Format] = " & dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value & " GROUP BY r.RequestName"
            else
                strSQL = "select sum(s.TransactionCount) 'hits', r.RequestName from TransactionSummary as s LEFT JOIN RepositoryDB.dbo.BLS_REQ as r ON s.[Format] = r.RequestID where s.CustomerNo = " & dbRS.Fields("CustomerNo").Value & " and s.SubNo = " & dbRS.Fields("SubNo").Value & " and s.City = " & dbRS.Fields("City").Value & " and s.TransactionDate >= '" & varYesterday & "' and s.TransactionDate <= '" & varToday & "' and s.[Format] = " & dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value & " GROUP BY r.RequestName"
            end if
            DBQuery.CommandText = strSQL

            Err.Clear
            set dbRS2 = DBQuery.Execute
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Response.Write("Could not get Transaction Summary - database error. SQL Script = " & strSQL)
            End If

            ' Count the hits into their respective total
            If (Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) = 25) or (Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) = 425 )Then
                MTTotalCount = MTTotalCount + dbRS2.Fields("hits").value
            ElseIf (Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value = 23)) Then
                ETTotalCount = ETTotalCount + dbRS2.Fields("hits").value
            ElseIf (Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) = 38) or _
                ((Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) >= 400) and _
                (Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) <= 499) or _
                ((Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) >= 800) and _
                (Trim(dbRS3.Fields("formatid").Value) <= 899))) Then
                    UpdateTotalCount = UpdateTotalCount + dbRS2.Fields("hits").value
            Else
                InquiryTotalCount = InquiryTotalCount + dbRS2.Fields("hits").value
            End If
            set dbRS2 = nothing
        end if
        dbRS3.MoveNext
    wend
    set dbRS3 = nothing
    UpdateTotalCount = UpdateTotalCount + MTTotalCount + ETTotalCount
    CustomerTotalCount = UpdateTotalCount + InquiryTotalCount

    ' show totals 
if Request.Form("present") = "xls" then 
    objXL.Cells(numRow,2) = Trim(dbRS.Fields("CustomerName").Value)
    objXL.Cells(numRow,3) = Trim(dbRS.Fields("City").Value)
    objXL.Cells(numRow,4) = UpdateTotalCount  
    objXL.Cells(numRow,5) = InquiryTotalCount                                       
    objXL.Cells(numRow,6) = CustomerTotalCount   
    objXL.Range("B" & numRow & ":F" & numRow).BORDERS.Weight = 2
    numRow = numRow + 1             
end if

if Request.Form("present") <> "xls" then 

    if varState <> "s" then
        Response.Write("<tr>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""left"">" & Trim(dbRS.Fields("CustomerName").Value) & "</td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center"">" & Trim(dbRS.Fields("City").Value) & "</td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center"">" & UpdateTotalCount & "</td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center"">" & InquiryTotalCount & "</td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("<td align=""center"">" & CustomerTotalCount & "</td>" & chr(13))
        Response.Write("</tr>" & chr(13))
    else
        IntervalNext = dateadd("n", varInterval, IntervalStart)
        Response.Write("<tr><td align=""left"">" & IntervalStart & " to&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>" & IntervalNext & "</td><td align=""center"" valign=""middle"">" & IntervalCounter & "</td></tr>" & chr(13))
    end if
    ' Response.Write("</table>" & chr(13))
end if

    'set dbRS2 = nothing
    dbRS.MoveNext
    AllUpdateCount = AllUpdateCount + UpdateTotalCount
    AllInquiryCount = AllInquiryCount + InquiryTotalCount
    AllMTCount = AllMTCount + MTTotalCount
    AllETCount = AllETCount + ETTotalCount
    AllTotalCount = AllTotalCount + CustomerTotalCount

'do grand totals    
wend
set dbRS = nothing

if Request.Form("present") <> "xls" then 
Response.Write("</table>" & chr(13))
if varCustomer = "0" and varState <> "s" then
    Response.Write("<h3>Grand Total Update = " & AllUpdateCount & "</h3>" & chr(13))
    Response.Write("<h3>Grand Total Inquiry = " & AllInquiryCount & "</h3>" & chr(13))
    Response.Write("<h3>Grand Total for All Customers = " & AllTotalCount & "</h3>" & chr(13))
    Response.Write("<h3>Grand Total Manual Transactions = " & AllMTCount & "</h3>" & chr(13))
    Response.Write("<h3>Grand Total Early Transactions = " & AllETCount & "</h3>" & chr(13))
end if

end if
end if
if Request.Form("present") <> "xls" then 
%><!--#include file="../Common/footer.inc"--><%
end if

if Request.Form("present") = "xls" then
objXL.Cells(numRow+1,4) = "Copyright " & Year(Date)
objXL.Cells(numRow+2,4) = "All Rights Reserved"

Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
If (Fso.FileExists("C:\Inetpub\temp\xl2.xlsx")) Then  
Set MyFile = Fso.GetFile("C:\Inetpub\temp\xl2.xlsx")   
MyFile.Delete
Set MyFile=nothing    
End If
Set Fso=nothing  

objWB.SaveAs "C:\Inetpub\temp\xl2.xlsx" 
objWB.Close 
objXL.Quit 
Response.Redirect "/temp/xl2.asp"
end if
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

This section of your code:

```
if Request.Form("present") = "xls" then 
    objXL.Cells(numRow,2) = Trim(dbRS.Fields("CustomerName").Value)
    objXL.Cells(numRow,3) = Trim(dbRS.Fields("City").Value)
    objXL.Cells(numRow,4) = UpdateTotalCount  
    objXL.Cells(numRow,5) = InquiryTotalCount                                       
    objXL.Cells(numRow,6) = CustomerTotalCount   
    objXL.Range("B" & numRow & ":F" & numRow).BORDERS.Weight = 2
    numRow = numRow + 1             
end if
```

Is referring to the `Cells` and `Range` objects with the wrong parent object.  The parent to these would be the worksheet, which you have previously set as `objWS`.  Also note that you really should set `objWS` like this:

```
Set objWS = objWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

because the `ActiveWorkbook` can change when you least expect it... :)